# Xcode designing for different size classes and screen sizes in Storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, nslayoutconstraint

I'm attempting to design a layout that will accommodate all screen sizes from 3.5 inch through iPad. Currently, I have a view controller that contains a UITableView and a custom cell with some user interface objects. I'm able to get the layout to show up fine with all of the constraints applied properly for screen sizes of 5.5 inches and above. However, on any screen sizes smaller than 5.5 inches, all of the user interface objects appear truncated because they're show up too far to the right rather than in the center where they're supposed to be.

When I check the constraints that anchor to the right side of the screen (trailing constraints), I notice they extend far beyond what the screen allows and this appears to be the cause of the objects getting truncated on the right hand side of the screen. These trailing constraints are attaching to the edge of the UITableView which is currently has a width of 600 which is too much for the smaller screens to display.

I've tried changing the class size to compact width, any height then reducing the size of the UITableView so it can fit on the smaller screens, but this causes the UITableView to be too small on larger screens (5.5 inch an above) and it leaves dead space on the right side of the screen. I used the assistant editor preview to verify this. I was surprised to see this behavior because I thought by selecting compact width it would create a separate size class that would not affect the larger screen sizes.

Is there any way I can make my layout fit all screen sizes with the correct proportions and so that it looks professional?

Comment: Auto-layout might seem confusing at first, but it will all make sense after a while. Due to the nature of your problem is impossible for us to offer any help without some kind of visual reference to the constraints you've set on your scene. Would it be possible to post some screenshots ?

Comment: Your table view should have constraints to all the edges of the screen, not a fixed width. Did you add constraints to your table view?

Comment: Thank you both for the responses. I think the problem may be what rdelmar mentioned. The only problem is that when I attempt to add constraints to the table view, the constraint boxes do not have a value in them and they appear to be disabled. Am I doing something wrong? 

@Aladinian, I agree. The complexity of constraint issues can be quite daunting. I'll have to check to see if I have the ability to post screenshots to the website.

Comment: Now, it appears I'm able to enter values for the UITableView constraints. I'm not sure why I wasn't able to before. I'm going to give that a try and I'll report back the results.

Comment: @rdelmar, adding the constraints to the UITableView worked! Is there any way I can give you credit for the correct answer? Thanks again to both of you for your help.